# How can I download zip files with discord.py?

Tags: python, file, discord, discord.py

Hey I created a command to hash files a user send, but the problem is that I only made this command for me because I need to hash zip files. The problem I have now is that Discord gives an error when it tries to download the zip file (It works fine with other filetypes like .jpg).

Code:

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def hash(self, ctx):
    if ctx.message.attachments:
        attachment = ctx.message.attachments[0]
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Hash",
                              description=attachment.filename,
                              color=discord.Color.blurple(),
                              timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
        await attachment.save(attachment.filename, use_cached=True)
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        file = attachment.filename

        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
        sha224 = hashlib.sha224()
        sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
        sha384 = hashlib.sha384()
        sha512 = hashlib.sha512()

        list_hash_objects = [md5, sha1, sha224, sha256, sha384, sha512]

        with open(file, 'rb') as opened_file:
            content = opened_file.read()
            for hash_object in list_hash_objects:
                hash_object.update(content)
                embed.add_field(name=hash_object.name,
                                value=f"`{hash_object.hexdigest()}`")

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        os.remove(attachment.filename)
    else:
        await ctx.send("No file found!")
```

Error:

```
discord.errors.HTTPException: 415 Unsupported Media Type (error code: 0): failed to get asset
```

It seems like .zip is an unsupported filetype but is there a way to download it? I would be grateful if soemone can help me.

Comment: "*It seems like .zip is an unsupported filetype*" - So why should there be a way to download it?

Comment: Might be an issue with discord.py. Have you asked them for support?